# Hibernate criteria example query gets multiple records

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a generic criteria query and it returns same records. I think there is something wrong with my student save method. Here is my save method;

```
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setId(Utility.generateUUID());
    student.setClassroom(selectedClassroom);
    student.setUrl(urlAddress);
    genericService.save(student);
```

When I try to get all Classrooms from datatable it returns 3 Classroom object which are same but there is only one record in Classroom table. The Problem is there are 3 student records which Classrooms are referencing to this classroom record.

My criteria query;

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
public <T> List<T> getByTemplate(T templateEntity) {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(templateEntity.getClass());
    criteria.add(Example.create(templateEntity));
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Entities;

```
public class Classroom{

    ....
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classroom", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Student> studentList;
}


public class Student{

    @JoinColumn(name = "classroom", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Classroom classroom;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the `student` `id` manually and don't you let `Hibernate` manage it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following to your criteria:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

This will retrieve distinct entities for Classroom even tought the inner join select will retrieve the three lines (one per user).

Comment: Setting the property hibernate.show_sql properties to true will show you the sql query executed. You will see the INNER JOIN clause build by Example.create().